# Typeorm repository providers gets reprovided without export

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

According to documentation:

> Nest encapsulates providers inside the module scope. You aren't able
>   to use the module providers elsewhere without importing them.

I have then made a module that encapsulates typeorms repositories and made providers for services (business logic). But for some reason, if i import DatabaseModule in another module and in its constructor @InjectRepository, the parameter is not null as would have been expected. The TypeOrmModule have never been exported and the repositories should not be available.

Am i misunderstanding something here?

Bonus question: Are there easier ways to decouple services from another package than below code?

```
const providers: Provider<any>[] = [
    {
        provide: OrganizationService,
        useFactory: (repository: Repository<Organization>) => {
            return new OrganizationService(repository);
        },
        inject: [getRepositoryToken(Organization)],
    }, {
        provide: FileService,
        useFactory: (repository: Repository<File>) => {
            return new FileService(repository);
        },
        inject: [getRepositoryToken(File)]
    }
];

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Organization, File])],
    providers: [...providers],
    exports: [...providers]
})
export class DatabaseModule { }
```

Comment: This might be because the `TypeOrmCoreModule` is a `@Global()` module, see https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/ff9ed20400b8b3d12c23edab492ceefe4b16ca86/lib/typeorm-core.module.ts#L32 I haven't looked at it in detail though. Global modules are imported only once and make their providers available globally in the whole application.

Comment: Be careful with repository instances that are not generated through an EntityManager, they will use their own transaction, outside of any currently running transaction. I don't think Singleton pattern should apply on them, to my mind it would be better to instanciate one from an EntityManager when you need it, and not injecting any repository instance.